# Application Navigation Works on iPhone but not on Android (Native Browser)

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, mobile

Demo: http://bbb.theinternetnoob.com

The error seems to occur when trying to load the navigation menu, either crashes or does not apply positioning or scrolling properly

Comment: You have a few javascript errors, also you are using jQuery which is not designed for mobile at all.

Comment: really..? where does it state that jquery is not supported for mobile? just curious, do you have a link so I can read it over? I recreated my own version of jQuery Mobile as jQuery Mobile seems to have a lot of bugs

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned it was a bit of a personal opinion, really mobile needs to be light as possible, we in house write JS by hand, and we create some really fast effects even on old android devices.